# Quotient of ideals of the ring of rational numbers with denominator prime to p.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R_p=${ $\frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb{Q} $ | gcd(n,p)=1 } and consider the ideals of $R_p$ : $p^{\nu}R_p$ and $p^{3\nu}R_p$.

Then   $\frac{p^{\nu}R_p}{p^{3\nu}R_p}$ is a cyclic group of order $p^{2\nu}$.

Things I've already checked:

$ a \in p^{\nu}R_p $  $\implies$ $a=p^{\nu}\frac{m}{n}$ so $p^{2\nu}a=p^{3\nu}\frac{m}{n}=0$, moreover if $gcd(m,n)=1 \implies p^{a\nu}a\neq0 $ with $ 0 \leq a <2$.

The rest of the axioms follow from the properties of the ring of rational numbers.

My question is if $\frac{p^{\nu}R_p}{p^{3\nu}R_p}$ is a cyclic group and an element of order $p^{2\nu}$ should be a generator how do I get all $a=p^{\nu}\frac{m}{n}$ from a single generator just using addition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements in your group have the form $p^v \frac{n}{m}$ where $\gcd(m,p)=1$. This means in particular that $\gcd(m,p^{3v})=1$ so you can find integers $a,b$ such that $am+bp^{3v}=1$. It follows that $\frac{1}{m}\equiv a\bmod p^{3v}$, so you can consider only elements of the form $p^v n$. Since $p^{3v}\equiv 0$, your group consists of the images of $\{p^v n | 0\leq n \leq p^{2v}-1\}$. It is now easy to see that $p^v$ is a generator for the (additive) group $p^vR_p /p^{3v}R_p$, or more generally any element $p^v n$ where $\gcd(n,p)=1$.

Comment: That was great, Bézout identity is so useful :)